# Why does rewrite rule ^(.*)$ set variable $1 to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have rewriting enabled.

I go to `domain/bar` and expect it to be rewritten to `domain/index.php?foo=bar`
but I get `domain/index.php?foo=index.php` instead :o

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?foo=$1
```

Why isn't `$1` set to bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me, try it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?foo=$1
```

Comment: Problem solved by adding:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: These two lines mean 'rewrite if the file/folder doesn't exist' right?